# Swift language. How to initialise my class by variable of superclass?

Tags: ios, swift

I have class inherited from UIButton

```
public class MyButton: UIButton {
    init(button: UIButton) {

    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to init my superclass(in my case UIButton) by variable of that class(in my case "button" in init method)?

**Objective-C solution.**

**.h File**

```
@interface UIButton(ExtraIntialiser)

- (id)initWithButton:(UIButton *)button;

@end

@interface MyButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *myProperty;
- (id)initWithButton:(UIButton)button someProperty:(NSObject *)someProperty;

@end;
```

**.m File**

```
@implementation UIButton(ExtraIntialiser)

- (id)initWithButton:(UIButton *)button {
    self = [button copy];
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation MyButton

- (id)initWithButton:(UIButton *)button someProperty:(NSObject *)someProperty {
    self = [super initWithButton:button];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.myProperty = someProperty;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense in Objective-C _or_ Swift. Exactly what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mimic this exact pattern in Swift, because of this line:

```
self = [button copy];
```

Swift won't allow you to assign to `self`. If you want to keep using this pattern, you'll have to copy over the attributes you want individually.

Also, in Objective-C, you're using a category. In Swift, your current code uses inheritance. If you want to mimic the same pattern, use a **[Swift extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)** instead.

Here's one possible implementation. There are, of course, other approaches:

```
public class MyButton : UIButton {
    var myProperty : NSObject?

    init(button : UIButton) {
        super.init()

        commonInit(button)
    }

    init(button : UIButton, property : NSObject) {
        self.myProperty = property

        super.init()

        commonInit(button)
    }

    func commonInit(button : UIButton) {
        let controlStates = [UIControlState.Normal, UIControlState.Selected, UIControlState.Highlighted]

        for controlState in controlStates {
            setTitle(button.titleForState(controlState), forState: controlState)
            setImage(button.imageForState(controlState), forState: controlState)
            setBackgroundImage(button.backgroundImageForState(controlState), forState: controlState)
        }
    }

    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}


extension UIButton {
    func buttonWithButton(button: UIButton) -> UIButton {
        return button.copy() as UIButton
    }
}
```

My advice to would be to instead refactor your code. If you really need this level of customization, create a button factory object that creates the buttons you need, and stop using copying from buttons altogether.

Comment: Yes, you have to work around the fact that an extension can't inject a designated initializer into a class.